# How to use iframe in dnn?

Tags: html, iframe, dotnetnuke-7

I want use iframe in dnn. I have a html file into skin path of site  . I use this code but get error.
Please advice.

```
   <iframe src="<%SkinPath%>/advertisement_anim.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: What error do you have there?

Comment: You should edit your post to add more information (error text)

Comment: Did you try `<%=SkinPath%>` instead of `<%SkinPath%>`?

Comment: Dan Sin : Thank you  It solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just post back my answer as reference.  As DNN based on Microsoft .NET, the following [syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_syntax.asp) would work:

```
<iframe src="<%=SkinPath%>/advertisement_anim.html"></iframe>
```